# Compile gzip with O3 optimization option

Tags: gcc, compilation, installation, gzip, compiler-optimization

I was wondering how to compile/install gzip in ubuntu from source files with gcc optimization flag O3.

the install instructions are as follows. I don't know how to add optimizations:

```
tar xvf gzip-1.2.4.tar
cd gzip-1.2.4
./configure
make
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

After running `./configure`, edit `CFLAGS=` in `Makefile` to contain `-O3`.  You could also do `CFLAGS="-O3" ./configure`.

Comment: there is no Makefile. There is only Makefile.in in gzip source code

Comment: _After_ you run `./configure`, there is a `Makefile`.  You need to read my answer more carefully.

Comment: I have gzip installed on my ubuntu with O3 level. How can I change to O0? @Adler

Comment: `tar xvf gzip-1.2.4.tar
cd gzip-1.2.4
CFLAGS="-O0" ./configure
make` override the installed O3 version? @Mark